# Garbage Collection in Ruby 2.x

Tags: ruby, garbage-collection

I have function which has a hash that has 100s of key value pairs.
Does setting it to nil at the end of the function will make ruby release that memory or help this variable to be garbage collected more easily?

```
def func
  hash ##a very big hash object
  ##Processing
  hash = nil
end
```

Comment: Yes. But that is not needed, because hash is a local variable in your example and will therefore garbage collected anyway.

Comment: This looks like premature optimization. Do you actually have a memory issue?

Comment: @Stefan Yes we have the problem of 4 sidekiq process taking more and more memory, until they are restarted. Hence we are looking at such solutions, only for very big objects,  to efficiently manage memory

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, these 100s of keys will increase heap_length over the time and when you reassign this reference variable to nil object the GC will not be called. Even if you call GC.start at this point the heap_free_num value will be an increase but total heap_length will remain the same. when you assign a reference variable nil. It will not call the Garbage Collector because the GC is only called in case ruby process needed to increase the heap_length by the introduction of a new variable or in a case of a new piece of code being call.

Comment: Thanks @untwal. We have now configured out GOD scripts to restart the ruby process, in case memory usage goes beyond a threshhold

Answer (score 0):

The garbage collector will pick up it has gone out of scope and clean from there. Doing the `hash = nil` simply changes the reference hash is pointing to, (now lack of) and the *original* hash remains in memory until **GC** collects it through its numerous cleanup methods.

Answer (score 0):

Not at all.

Immediately after this [redundant] call to `hash = nil`, the scope, defining the *local variable `hash`* is ended. That said, the variable will go out of scope and next time `GC` will do it’s job, it’ll be collected.

The more generic answer would be “no, setting the variable to `nil` won’t do anything related to GC, but it will decrease a reference counter of nested objects by one.” In the case when `hash` contains objects, that are not referred from any other places, changing the value of `hash` (not necessarily to `nil`, to empty hash / any other value is fine as well,) will decrease an amount of references of it’s nested objects to zero, and, therefore, will force them to be garbage collected.

**NB** Please also refer to significant comment by Jörg W Mittag below.

Comment: … assuming that there even *is* a reference counter, which is actually not true for most Ruby implementations. Most Ruby implementations use a tracing GC, not a reference counting one.

Comment: @JörgWMittag oh, right, thanks. I was switching languages too often in the near past, resulting a mess in my head.

Answer (score 0):

**tl;dr**: No.

Longer explanation:

1. The variable goes out of scope at the end of the method anyway.
2. The garbage collector does not necessarily collect dead objects as soon as there no longer are any references to them. In fact, depending on how much memory you have and how long your program is running, the garbage collector may never even run and thus not collect any objects at all.
3. Even when the garbage collector runs, there is no guarantee as to which objects it will collect and which not. Some garbage collectors have maximum times they are allowed to run and will only collect as many objects as they can during that time.
4. (This should be obvious but bears repeating.) If there are other references to that object, it won't even be eligible for garbage collection in the first place.

The Ruby Language Specification does not say anything at all about how memory is managed. Different Ruby implementations use very different memory management implementations, e.g. YARV uses a simple mark-sweep collector, Rubinius uses Immix, and JRuby, IronRuby, Topaz, Opal don't even have their own, they use the underlying platform's memory management. (Which again may be totally different, e.g. just for JRuby, HotSpot has 4 different GCs, JRockit has 2, J9 has 2.)